# How to use Twitter api to know user's location in jsp servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, twitter

I want to use Twitter API to know the User's location. I am working with jsp's and I am not able to get how to make a call to the Twitter API. Please can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The user's location can be found when querying for a **single user**:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

Or when querying for **multiple users**:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

In order to get this data through your JSP, you can use either the **JSON or the XML parser**. If you're looking for a **library**, check here:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#java